# "git checkout -- ." equivalent on windows

Tags: git

To discard non commited changes I run `git checkout -- .` on Ubuntu. But on windows this command doesn't work. Is there any alternatives to this on windows?

Comment: I normally use `git checkout -f`.

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

This will do it for you too. Be careful.

Comment: What are the risks? Is it exactly same as -- . option?